# how to print 2 values in one xpath or how else to do it?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I don't think I can get away with one XPATH so it is just to illustrate the idea. I know I can write a simple python script but I'd prefer to use a tool, e.g. Oxygen (not xmlstarlet if possible!)

suppose I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<model>
    <object name='obj1'>
        <field type='int' name='fld1'/>
        <field type='string' name='fld2'/>
    </object>
</model>
```

I want names of all the `int` fields. That's easy:

```
/model/object/field[@type='int']/@name
```

Now say I want to print the object name along with the field name. How can I do it?
I guess XSLT is the answer... trouble is, I hardly remember any of it and can't find in Oxygen how to play with it.

EDIT: expected output
obj1 fld1
obj2 fld7  (supposing I had them in the xml)

Comment: show me the expected output... alos

Comment: What version of xpath do you use?

Comment: @JirkaŠ. as in oXygen - 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In xpath 2.0 you could make following:

```
for $x in /model/object/field[@type = 'int'] return concat($x/@name, ' ', $x/../@name)
```

It returns

```
fld1 obj1
```

Comment: It should be pure xpath 2.0. Just note it returns string as far as concat() returns string.

Comment: didn't know you can do such things in XPATH, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the posted XPath 2.0 solution using `for .. in` you can also use `/model/object/field[@type='int']/concat(../@name, ':', @name)`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following XSL (perhaps it could be useful to somebody):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Integer Fields</h2>

                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Object Name</th>
                        <th>Field Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//object/field/[@type='int']">
                        <tr>
                            <td> <xsl:value-of select="parent::node()/@name"/> </td>
                            <td> <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```